# Show/Hide div id when passing another div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

What I need:

1. Show 'article_footer' by default
2. When I pass 'article_footer_base' > 'article_footer' hides
3. When I then scroll back up passed 'article_footer_base' > 'article_footer' then becomes visible again.

Tried a million things - cant get it to work :( Help!? The below just doesn't really work at all. I've just been trying to nab stuff of SO

My HTML:

```
<div class="d3-d10">
<div class="article_header">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <ul class="center">
            <li><a href="/profile/{{ username }}" class="user_avatar">{{ gravatamatic:quicky
                email = "{email}"
                size  = "32"
                }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="/profile/{{ username }}">{{ username }}</a> on {{ current_date format="M jS, Y" }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="d3-d10 article_content">
    {{ copy }}
</div>
<div class="d3-d10 source_link article_block_element">
{{ if source_link }}
    <p class="center">Article originally published at {{ source_link }}</p>
{{ /if }}
    <span class="icon-emblem"></span>
</div>
<div class="d3-d10 article_block_element article_footer_base">
    <ul class="left">
    <li><button class="global_btn_red"><span class="icon-upvote"></span>upvote</button> <span class="bold">23 people</span> have upvoted this</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My footer (being called in a partial):

```
</section> <!-- Ending full width section -->
<div class="article_footer">
    <ul class="left">
        <li><button class="global_btn_red"><span class="icon-upvote"></span>upvote</button> <span class="bold">23 people</span> have upvoted this</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
      <li><button class="global_btn_white"><span class="icon-saved"></span> save for later</button></li>
      <li><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status={{ title }} https://thedigest.org/articles/{{ segment_3 }} - by @digestuk" target="blank" class="global_btn_white icon_btn_white"><span class="icon-twitter"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://thedigest.org/articles/{{ segment_3 }}" class="global_btn_white icon_btn_white"><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="mailto:support@thedigest.org" class="global_btn_white icon_btn_white"><span class="icon-flag"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
/**
* Article more dropdown
*/
$('.article_footer').show();

var entryheight = $('.article_footer_base').height();

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 350 && y < entryheight) {
         $('.article_footer').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('.article_footer').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your html as well

Comment: Where is `.article_footer_base` and what is the relevant CSS? Otherwise we don't know when the one passes the other.

Comment: @SanderKoedood .article_footer_base is in my html snippet documented above.

Does the CSS matter? I haven't got anything on there except for styles .... ?

Comment: You're right, I overlooked it. But CSS matters, because otherwise I don't know when `.article_footer_base` passes `.article_footer`. Perhaps you could make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) out of it?

Comment: @SanderKoedood Ok cool, got something basic put together here http://jsfiddle.net/m7kjzbmv/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

The jQuery that will work is the following:

```
/**
* Article more dropdown
*/
$('.article_footer').show();

var entryheight = $('.article_footer_base').offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if (y > entryheight) {
         $('.article_footer').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('.article_footer').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

## TS;WM

(too short, want more)

First, we remove [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad). I don't know what 350 stands for, and neither will anyone else.

Then, we check what we need. In this case, it's the [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) of the item. The offset, in short, is the distance the item is from the top. We put it in the variable `entryheight`, as shown above. Now, on scroll (`$(document).scroll()`), all we need to do is compare the `scrollTop()` from the window to the offset from the item. If `y` (the scroll position of the window + the height of the window) is bigger than `entryheight`, we know we've passed `.article_footer_base`. Else, we want `.article_footer` visible.

Here you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/m7kjzbmv/4/

Comment: Hey Sander, that's almost it! Except I want the div to hide as soon as it hits the '.article_footer_base' div

Using the code ontop - it seems as the window waits for the user to scroll past the '.article_footer_base' by the distance of the window. 

I want it to hide the second it hits 'article_footer_base'

Comment: Easy enough, add the window height. I updated it for you.

Comment: Sander - you are a King amongst men! hah! Thanks a lot dude :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.